# Paypal PayFlowPro send email after transaction

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway

I have website integrated with Paypal PayFlowPro API. On payment success our application sends an email to user but sometimes due to some code changes or SMTP server issue an email dosen't go to user which in turns create some confusion to user.
I would like to know that is there any way that Paypal can send email to user on payment success or failure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible with Payflow Pro.
Instead, I would suggest looking into 'some code changes or SMTP server issue'. For example, only mark the payment as completed if an email has gone through, and periodically check all payments that are success from PayPal but haven't been marked as completed on your end.